# "I've lived in __ two years" vs "I lived in __ two years"

Tags: difference, present-perfect, past-simple

There is a question that's confused me for a long time.

Let's say I'm in Korea right now and I get asked 
"How did you get the American accent" while talking to a stranger at a pub, can I say either:

> "I lived in California for 2 years"
>   or
>   "I've lived in California for 2 years"?

I suppose the former one is only acceptable since the latter is implied that I still live in California and now I am in California.

Am I right here?

Comment: Possible duplicate: every other preterite vs perfect question :)

Comment: In brief - yes, you are right!